# Server Density or Scout-like Services for Windows?

Tags: windows, monitoring, saas

I've been very impressed with agent-based / SaaS-like monitoring services such as [Scout](http://scoutapp.com/) and [Server Density](http://www.serverdensity.com/).  They both provide very nice trending, alerting, and reporting capabilities for my *nix boxes, and I need to find something similar for Windows.

Can anyone out there recommend such a tool?

It is important that this tool is a centralized service in line with the aforementioned products, as the deployment environment is owned by a lean team with limited resources.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Server Density has a [Windows monitoring agent](http://www.serverdensity.com/windows/) now, so I'd still recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what the size of your Windows install-base is, but if you want to go "whole hog" the Microsoft monitoring system is [System Center Operations Manager 2007 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/operationsmanager/en/us/default.aspx).  It's not exactly cheap compared to other solutions out there, but it basically has every conceivable monitoring and alerting option covered.

They *almost* have it completely scriptable via PowerShell.

However, it can be a real pain to get configured.  You are probably better off sticking with the product you already understand/use in a "lean" team.

Comment: Thank you very much for the recommendation - I should have been more specific about the size of the environment, as it will be somewhere around a dozen machines to begin with.  I'm trying to keep support infrastructure as lean as possible for this project, so something like Server Density will probably work better.

Thanks again, though.  I'll keep this in mind for our larger environments.

Comment: Ssystem Center Essentials. Cheaper, handles that well, still. One machine separate is not a problem - even fo r a dozen machines. Virtualize it.

Answer (score 0):

My company, [Panopta](http://www.panopta.com), has a Windows agent that can be installed locally on a server that feeds metrics to our central monitoring system for combined alerting and reporting with results from our Linux agent and remote network service checks.