# Any SaaS server monitoring tools around?

Tags: monitoring, saas

I guess the title should say it all. I'm looking for a solution that would allow me monitor my Windows servers (disk space, running services, memory,...) as a SaaS solution. I do not wish to install the monitoring tools myself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at : http://serverfault.com/questions/125814/server-density-or-scout-like-services-for-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not wish to install the monitoring tools myself.

As David said, there is no way to monitor disk space, running services, memory, etc without installing at least some kind of software (monitoring agent) on your system.

What we do is to simply use a good website monitoring service like AlertFox/AlertSite/Gomez,.... While it can not report on CPU use, it reports on the key criteria of your site: uptime, performance and functionality.

I know that AlertFox has free accounts: http://www.alertfox.com/free-website-monitoring/

Answer (score 1):

Data Center Knowledge has a list of Cloud/SaaS Monitoring providers. Here's the link:

http://www.datacenterknowledge.com/archives/2010/02/04/cloud-monitoring-services-a-resource-guide/

And here is another resource: 
14 Ways to do Server Monitoring from the Cloud
http://www.rackaid.com/resources/server-monitoring-cloud/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[ServerDensity.com](http://www.serverdensity.com/) is also some kind of nice tool. At least they have a nice frontend and some nifty features like an iPhone/Android app etc. But sometimes the lack performance and they are not the cheapest I think.