# Open Source Monitoring for Windows

Tags: windows, monitoring, open-source

There is a fantastic overview of monitoring solutions here:

[What tool do you use to monitor your servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)

Strikingly, none of the options seem to be:

- Open Source
- Windows-only (not Linux installs with Windows agents)
- Robust (there are a few Windows efforts in the list that have not been updated for a long time).

Am I missing something?  If I want to monitor my Windows servers, are my options to either purchase a commercial solution or run a Linux server?

Comment: how about nagwin

Comment: Hmmm... the press release says it can be downloaded from one of two locations, both of which don't have a download... Any idea how supported that packaging is?  http://www.nagios.org/news/77-news-announcements/273-introducing-nagwin-nagios-for-windows

Comment: Did you see the notice on the question you linked to?  This question exists because it has historical significance, **but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**.

Comment: What exactly makes this question off-topic?  Reading http://serverfault.com/faq I see that questions about monitoring are on-topic and I do not see anything that fits my question on the off-topic list.

Comment: once again its a bad closure reason, read his question carefully. Other then that I've never used nagwin, sorry.

Comment: @tonyroth, if you really believe this or other questions closed badly, then please make your case on [meta](http://meta.serverfault.com/).  There is already a [question open about this](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3096/why-was-my-question-considered-not-acceptable-for-server-fault).

Comment: Give http://rexmonitor.com a try. It's not open source, but it's free.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned what version of windows servers you are trying to monitor or what services/applications you are interested in monitoring, but you are NOT limited to buying a commercial solutionor running a linux server yourself.  You have several choices:

1. Server 2008's Windows Performance and reliability monitor (included with server 2008)
   which includes Windows Reliability and Performance Monitor, which is a Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in that combines the functionality of previous stand-alone tools including Performance Logs and Alerts, Server Performance Advisor, and System Monitor. It provides a graphical interface for customizing Data Collector Sets and Event Trace Sessions.

It also includes Reliability Monitor, an MMC snap-in that tracks changes to the system and compares them to changes in system stability, providing a graphical view of their relationship.
Great technet article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771692%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), although it is not my favorite choice because of the Micro-softiness of it.

2 . Consider using a Software As A Service monitoring tool like the ones discussed in this post [Any SaaS server monitoring tools around?](https://serverfault.com/questions/190865/any-saas-server-monitoring-tools-around)